# is it Possible to get null by using [NSDate date]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I want to know that in very rare exceptional case it is possible to get date = null using following code `NSDate *date = [NSDate date]`

Actually I am getting Current date but some time very few user get null value. It is my analysis because my application is getting crash from user side but when I am testing I am not getting any crash in application.

due to time zone is it possible to get Null value by using `[NSDate date]`

Comment: That will never return null

Comment: It can not be null, could be other reason makes the app crash.

Comment: @danh , I have also same thinking, it has other reason, My team does not get any crash just few user getting crash. I am also looking for other point for getting crash

Comment: @DuyNguyen, I have also same thinking, it has other reason, My team does not get any crash just few user getting crash. I am also looking for other point for getting crash